# Why are the registration requirements different for posting questions vs posting answers?

Tags: discussion, new-users, anonymous-visitors

If you want to post a question you have to confirm your email address but if you want to post an answer you don't.

For purposes of spam reduction it seems like requiring an email address for both would be ideal. Any particular reason why that isn't done?

Comment: Maybe because it's question titles and blurbs that are shown in search engine results, not answers.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure but something that might be a reason is this:

It doesn't matter a lot when the answerer's account gets lost. The worst thing that can happen is that the answerer doesn't get his 'reward'. If the account of a question asker gets lost, he can't follow up any more. Also voting and accepting isn't possible. Hence, the quality gets down and you get some angry users.

Also, asking a question is somewhat *taking* from the community. Providing an answer is *giving*. I think they want to get as much useful stuff in and as much crap out.