# Voting makes the app crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, ios-app

If you vote on a post, the latest beta of the iOS app crashes instantly.

Just had this when I tried to upvote [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267278/245360) and it is broken for all subsequent questions and answers I have tried.

---

- App Version: 1.4.0.236
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 9.0.2 (Build 13A452)

---

The fix (1.4.0.237) didn't fix it. It is still broken. Tapping on answers does nothing. On questions it still crashes.

---

Fix 1.4.0.238 fixes the issue for questions. Answers are unresponsive now. The app doesn't crash any more when clicking, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Of course it does.

Comment: What? Is it anti-voting day? Did I really miss that?

Comment: No, it's make a major change without testing it day.  Otherwise known as Friday.

Comment: Ah. Did the VoiceOver changed break it?

Comment: In a way. I completely rewrote the score view in Swift, renamed some callbacks, and didn't update Interface Builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix is incoming.

I changed the signature of the vote actions from `upVoteTapped(_:)` and `downVoteTapped(_:)` to `toggleUpvote()` and `toggleDownvote()` but failed to update the XIB.

You'd think when I worked the UI I would actually tap on things, but I didn't.

**UPDATE** Actually fixed this time.  Not sure why it wasn't crashing for me but long story short I renamed a function that I thought was internal, the header was out of sync, I missed the warning, an invalid message was sent to an object.  Maybe languages with header files actually are bad...

Comment: Tapping. It's always tapping. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard i don't get the joke :-s

Comment: Still broken here. Tapping on answers does nothing. On questions it still crashes.

Comment: @Pat probably Brian needs to push the fix first and you'll have to update the app.

Comment: @Ooker http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/152859 :)

Comment: Already done I think @sha

Comment: @Pat oh. So maybe the bug is more evasive than what poor Brian thought at first... :/

Comment: I guess... @sha

Comment: @PatrickHofman you guys can really notify each other with only three first charactes?

Comment: Yes. We do @ook

Comment: @PatrickHofman Should actually be fixed now.

Comment: Answers still don't work. Questions do.

Comment: @PatrickHofman *sigh* I think it's fixed now.

Comment: It does! Thanks @BrianNickel